# T-SQL Left-Join with 1 row (limi, subselect)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, left-join

I already read a lot on that topic but I´m unable to get it to work for my case.

I have the following situation:

- A list of orderitems (the main datasets I want to get)
- Articles which have a 1:1 relation to an order item
- A n:m Jointable "Articlesupplier" which creates a relation between an article and a
  partner
- A Partner table with detailed information about partners.

Target:
One dataset per OrderItem and from the suppliers I only want to get the first one found in the join. No priorization required.

Tables:

Table `IDX_ORDERITEM`

```
id,article_id
```

Table `IDX_ARTICLE`

```
id,name
```

Table `IDX_ARTICLESUPPLIER`

```
article_id,partner_id
```

Table `IDX_PARTNER`

```
id,abbr
```

My actual statement (short version):

```
SELECT IDX_ORDERITEM.id
FROM         
dbo.IDX_ORDERITEM AS IDX_ORDERITEM

-- ARTICLE --
INNER JOIN dbo.IDX_ARTICLE AS IDX_ARTICLE
ON IDX_ORDERITEM.article_id=IDX_ARTICLE.id

-- SUPPLIER VIA ARTICLE --  
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT TOP(1) IDX_PARTNER.id, IDX_PARTNER.abbr 
  FROM IDX_PARTNER, IDX_ARTICLESUPPLIER
  WHERE IDX_PARTNER.id = IDX_ARTICLESUPPLIER.partner_id
  AND IDX_ARTICLESUPPLIER.article_id=IDX_ARTICLE.id) AS IDX_PARTNER_SUPPLIER 
  ON IDX_PARTNER_SUPPLIER.id=IDX_ARTICLE.supplier_partner_id

WHERE 1>0
ORDER BY orderitem.id DESC
```

But it seems I can´t access IDX_ARTICLE.id in the subquery. I get the following error message:

> The multi-part identifier "IDX_ARTICLE.id" could not be bound.

Is the problem that the Article alias has the same name as the table name?

Thanks a lot in advance for possible ideas,
Mike

Comment: That's a really unfortunate, bad naming convention to call your tables `IDX_......` - that would intuitively refer to an **index** - not a table!

Comment: You are right, but unfortunately that´s not my databse and the name of the ERP System is "IDX", that´s the reason for this naming convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I changed your aliases, and the subquery to which you were joining (I also modified that subquery so it doesn't use implicit joins anymore), though this changes where mostly cosmetics. The actual important change was the use of `OUTER APPLY` instead of `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT OI.id
FROM dbo.IDX_ORDERITEM AS OI
INNER JOIN dbo.IDX_ARTICLE AS A
    ON OI.article_id = A.id
OUTER APPLY  
  (SELECT TOP(1) P.id, P.abbr 
   FROM IDX_PARTNER AS P
   INNER JOIN IDX_ARTICLESUPPLIER AS SUP
        ON P.id = SUP.partner_id
   WHERE SUP.article_id = A.id
   AND P.id = A.supplier_partner_id) AS PS 
ORDER BY OI.id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown because the below piece of query

```
 (SELECT TOP(1) IDX_PARTNER.id, IDX_PARTNER.abbr 
  FROM IDX_PARTNER, IDX_ARTICLESUPPLIER
  WHERE IDX_PARTNER.id = IDX_ARTICLESUPPLIER.partner_id
  AND IDX_ARTICLESUPPLIER.article_id=IDX_ARTICLE.id) AS IDX_PARTNER_SUPPLIER
```

cannot be considered as a correlated sub-query and `IDX_ARTICLE.id` is referenced in it in the same manner we reference a field of outer query in a correlated sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems.

According to your DDLs there is no IDX_ARTICLE.supplier_partner_id which you refer to in the left join on clause.

Second, I'm quite sure you cannot use IDX_ARTICLE.id in your derived table. Simply add IDX_ARTICLESUPPLIER.article_id to your derived table selected fields and use it in your left join on clause against IDX_ARTICLE.id.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to avoid nested queries. If I can, I will always rewrite it using CTE.

```
WITH    Part_Sup
          AS (
               SELECT TOP ( 1 ) P.id
                   ,P.abbr
                   ,SUP.article_id
                FROM IDX_PARTNER AS P
                INNER JOIN IDX_ARTICLESUPPLIER AS SUP
                    ON P.id = SUP.partner_id
             )
    SELECT OI.id
        FROM dbo.IDX_ORDERITEM AS OI
        INNER JOIN dbo.IDX_ARTICLE AS A
            ON OI.article_id = A.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Part_Sup AS PS
            ON PS.article_id = A.Id
               AND PS.id = A.supplier_partner_id
        ORDER BY OI.id DESC;
```

Next I rewritten the first query to use `ROW_NUMBER()` function instead of using `TOP (1)` using `ROW_NUMBER` you can control which results you want and what you don't want.

```
WITH    Part_Sup
          AS (
               SELECT P.id
                   ,P.abbr
                   ,SUP.article_id
                   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY P.id, P.abbr ) AS RowNum
                FROM IDX_PARTNER AS P
                INNER JOIN IDX_ARTICLESUPPLIER AS SUP
                    ON P.id = SUP.partner_id
             )
    SELECT OI.id
        FROM dbo.IDX_ORDERITEM AS OI
        INNER JOIN dbo.IDX_ARTICLE AS A
            ON OI.article_id = A.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Part_Sup AS PS
            ON PS.article_id = A.Id
               AND PS.id = A.supplier_partner_id
               AND RowNum = 1
        ORDER BY OI.id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Lamak - you solved it :)
I used your input to extract the basic solution to make it a bit easier to read for others which have the same problem:

**Using OUTER APPLY (without ORDER_ITEM Table here):**

```
SELECT IDX_ARTICLE.id AS AR_ID, IDX_PARTNER_SUPPLIER.id, IDX_PARTNER_SUPPLIER.abbr
FROM         
dbo.IDX_ARTICLE AS IDX_ARTICLE

OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT TOP(1) _PARTNER.id, _PARTNER.abbr
    FROM IDX_PARTNER AS _PARTNER
    INNER JOIN IDX_ARTICLESUPPLIER AS _ARTICLESUPPLIER
        ON _PARTNER.id = _ARTICLESUPPLIER.partner_id
    WHERE _ARTICLESUPPLIER.article_id=IDX_ARTICLE.id
    AND _ARTICLESUPPLIER.deleted IS NULL) AS IDX_PARTNER_SUPPLIER

WHERE IDX_ARTICLE.id=67
```